# Why isn't a picture drawn? (PHP)

Tags: php, draw

Why doesn't my class draw a picture?
If i make it a only function it runs, but in class it doesnt work :(.
I am new in PHP classes (Java classes is not new for me).

```
<?php

class Schild
{

    public function __construct(){
        $text = $_GET['text'];
        $picture = imagecreatefrompng("bild.png");
        $pika = imagecreatefromjpeg("pika.jpg");
        $pika_size = getimagesize("pika.jpg");
    }

    public function drawPicture()
    {
        $im = imagecolorallocate ($picture, 255, 0, 255);
        imagettftext($picture, 111, 0, 100, 100,$im , "Marmellata(Jam)_demo.ttf", $text);

        # int ImageCopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )
        imagecopy($picture, $pika, 50, 50, 0, 0, $pika_size[0], $pika_size[1]);

        $zufall = rand(1,99999999);

        #header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        imagejpeg($picture);
        imagedestroy($picture);

    }
}

$schild1 = new Schild();
$schild1->drawPicture();
?>
```

Comment: What happens when it's a class?  What is the output?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

class Schild
{
    protected $picture;
    protected $pika;
    protected $pika_size;
    protected $text;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->text = $_GET['text'];
        $this->picture = imagecreatefrompng("bild.png");
        $this->pika = imagecreatefromjpeg("pika.jpg");
        $this->pika_size = getimagesize("pika.jpg");
    }

    public function drawPicture()
    {
        $im = imagecolorallocate ($this->picture, 255, 0, 255);
        imagettftext($this->picture, 111, 0, 100, 100,$im , "Marmellata(Jam)_demo.ttf", $this->text);

        # int ImageCopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )
        imagecopy($this->picture, $this->pika, 50, 50, 0, 0, $this->pika_size[0], $this->pika_size[1]);

        $zufall = rand(1,99999999);

        #header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        imagejpeg($this->picture);
        imagedestroy($this->picture);

    }
}

$schild1 = new Schild();
$schild1->drawPicture();
?>
```

The problem is you are declaring variables in `__construct`, but they are local variables. As soon as `__construct()` finishes executing, it deletes all of the local variables. You must declare them as CLASS variables using the `$this` keyword, so that they are accessible to your other function.

Comment: Rogue - I would add a line or two (in text) to say what you actually did and why, so the poster and others can learn vs just copyand pasting.

Comment: @RyanB I added a description about 10 seconds after my original post :)

Comment: Probably as I was typing. Cheers :)